# Pushwoosh Angular simple POST request returns 400

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, coffeescript, pushwoosh

I'm trying to send a simple POST request to the push-woosh remote API to create a push notification. (code is in coffee, I'm building an app using Ionic Framework)

```js
@sendPushMessage =  ->
        pushMessage = 
            {
                "request": {
                    "application": PW_APP_ID,
                    "auth": API_TOKEN,
                    "notifications": [{
                        "send_date": "now", 
                        "ignore_user_timezone": true, 
                        "content": "message",
                        "platforms": [1]
                    }]
                }
            };
        formattedPM = JSON.stringify(pushMessage)
        console.log("JSON sent :"+formattedPM)
        $http.post(createUrl, formattedPM).success((data, status, headers, config) ->
          console.log("success")
          return
        ).error (data, status, headers, config) ->
          console.log("failure")
          return
```

The problem is that it returns a bad request error 400. It gets the OPTIONS but it never posts the data. I tried to post the exact same data with Postman and it worked gracefully. So here I am wondering why it doesn't work in Chrome.

I also tried to whitelist the domain in the app config, in vain.

Can somebody help me out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my angular config and it now works.

```js
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  //Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request (aka preflight)
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
}]);
```